# Need to adjust web service clock skew

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a legacy web service (asmx) that actually has no defined binding at all.  It doesn't use any security and doesn't need to.  When setting the WebServiceBinding of the one and only web service, I simply have:

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

...which I'm sure uses a basicHttpBinding under the hood.  The problem that I am having (and lots of others as well as I found from my research) is that when someone uses a machine with a time that is more than 5 minutes different than the server, we get the nasty clock skew error.  I've searched high and low and have seen many solutions but none for simply adjusting the clock skew.  All of the solutions seem to want you to create a custom binding, which is fine until I get to the security element.  I'm not using any but still need to set the clock skew.  I've found code that does it at runtime but on the client only.  Ideally, if I could do something like this, I'd be happy (but it doesn't seem that I can - because I'm missing authenticationMode):

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding Name="ClockSkewBinding">
      <security>
        <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
        <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

...and then, of course change my server binding to:

```
[WebServiceBinding(Name="ClockSkewBinding")]
```

...and use the same binding for the endpoint on the client.

I've already read the MSDN article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468.aspx and have spent hours upon hours pouring over web sites trying to find something similar but to no avail.  I am not interested in applying any type of security to this and I completely understand the implications of that.  I just need to change the clock skew on a simple basicHttpBinding with no security.

Thanks in advance!